# On the existence of an injective recursive function such that all its values are also its indexes.

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

Kleene's second recursion theorem easily yields a self-referential program. What is more, it gives a program $P_a$ that computes any computable function of its index $a$ and its input. But does an injective recursive function exist, such that all its values are also its indexes. In other words does an injective recursive function $g$ exist, such that for each value $g(n)$ the program $P_{g(n)}$ computes the said function $g$?

**EDIT:** To make it absolutely clear let $\varphi_a$ denote the one argument function calculated by the program $P_a$ with index $a$. I am looking for an injective function $g$ such that for all natural numbers $n$, $\varphi_{g(n)}(x)=g(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy for $g$ to exist if you don't require that $g$ hits *all* indices for a program that computes $g$. In that case we can say, essentially

$$\begin{align}g(n) = &\text{let } x
= \text{the source for this program (by any standard quine construction)}\\
   &\text{in the index of the program that consists of }n\text{ "skip"s followed by }x
\end{align}$$

Variants of this construction can be produced under even very abstract conditions on how we're enumerating computable functions (basically the $s$-$n$-$m$ theorem has to hold, and composition of functions has to be computable, and perhaps one or two similar conditions which I may have forgotten).

---

However, $g$ *cannot* exist if we require it to output *all* of its indices. If it did, we could use it to decide the halting problem. Suppose we want to know whether Turing machine $T$ halts. Now consider the program

$$ P_q(n) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if }T\text{ halts in at most }n\text{ steps} \\
g(n) &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $P_q$ program computes $g$ exactly if $T$ *doesn't* halt. So we can find out whether $T$ halts by enumerating all of the outputs of $P_q$ and look for either $0$ or $q$ itself.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Makholm. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "skips." Assume for a moment that I am familiar with some quine construction. Would you explain in more detail how you define $g$ under the said abstract conditions?

Comment: @Ivan: "Skip" is a command that does nothing -- I'm here supposing that you're encoding computable functions as source code in some programming language. If you're thinking in terms of Turing machines instead, you can imagine adding $n$ new states that are never actually reached.

Comment: I looked up the general construction (see for example Jones, _Computability and Complexity From a Programming Perspective_, lemma 1.4.4). The relevant property is that there's always a computable _injective_ function $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ such that $P_x$ and $P_{f(x,y)}$ compute the same function for all $x$ and $y$. The proof from general abstract conditions is rather involved, since all it assumes is Kleene's fixpoint theorem and the s-m-n theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure it's lemma $1.4.4$? I did not find it.

Comment: I am in fact thinking in terms of UMR computable functions, and I'd like to see the general construction.

Comment: @Ivan: Sorry, typo. It's 14.4.4 (on page 234 in my copy).

Comment: It's on page 233 in the revised PDF found at http://www.diku.dk/~neil/Comp2book.html -- the tricky details are in Theorem 14.4.2 one page earlier.

Comment: I'm sorry, sir, but upon closer examination, the book proves something different from what I am looking for, does it not? I've been working on this for some time. I've tried applying proposition 14.4.2 to different functions, but failed. Not even the padding lemma was any help. And the function you defined in your answer is not defined in a language I speak. May I get some more help with this?

Comment: @Ivan: The Padding Lemma states that a particular computable function $\pi$ exists. Apply Kleene's recursion theorem (14.3.4) directly to an index for $\pi$. The $\mathtt e$ it produces will then satisfy your condition.

Comment: Then, writing $[\![x]\!]$ for $\phi_x$, we have for all $d$: $$[\![ [\![\mathtt e]\!](d) ]\!] = [\![ \pi(\mathtt e,d)]\!] = [\![ \mathtt e ]\!]$$ where the first equality is from the recursion theorem and the second is from the padding lemma. And $[\![ \mathtt e ]\!]$ is injective because $\pi$ is and the recursion theorem clearly preserves injectivity.